Gnuplot: Verbose mode in text with underscore
I try to automate my plots.
Unfortunatley, I have underscore (_) in my file and column names that I would like to plot.
The result of this are textsubscriptions in the output, which I do not want to have.
Is there a way to tell Gnuplot to ignore underscores as textsubscriptions and print them as underscore directly?
I am not looking for a single solution like \_ or so, but for a global method.

Any response...?

Have you checked for example help key option noenhanced?
or
help <your terminal>? There should be an option noenhanced as well.
